# How does git rebase work for different versions of master?

Tags: git

Hopefully this isn't repeating someone else's question. I know there's a lot on the topic of rebasing, but trying to wrap my head around how it works when there are two copies of the same branch out in the wild.

**Scenario:**

Person A is working on a new feature...

```
(master)     M1 -- M2 -- M3
              \ 
(feature)       -- F1 -- F2
```

Person B just has his own version of pretty much the same thing, but a few less commits.

```
(master)     M1 -- M2
              \ 
(feature)       -- F1
```

So now, Person A rebases by doing something like `git rebase master` followed by a `git push -f`. Now he has something like:

```
(master)     M1 -- M2 -- M3
                          \ 
(feature)                  -- F1 -- F2
```

Cool. Perfect. Let's celebrate! Oh, but not so fast. Now Person B wants to get his hands on the feature branch, so he does a git reset to make sure he doesn't screw things up (`git reset --hard origin/feature`). And no, he doesn't care about losing any local changes.

So this is the part I don't understand. Person B now has a feature branch that's rebased to a copy of master that doesn't exist for him. Would look something like:

```
(master)     M1 -- M2 -- ??
                          \ 
(feature)                  -- F1 -- F2
```

Can I get some help understanding what happens in this situation? It may seem like an edge case, but it happens for me quite a bit. In my situation, I'm both Person A and Person B, but running the same code on two different machines. I don't always switch back to master and pull the latest when working solely in a branch. This all works, and once I pull master the logs look correct (they match), but I don't really understand what happens when master doesn't match up.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Person B would have the commit M3 in their repo, but `master` would still be pointing to M2 (until Person B ran `git pull` while on `master`).

Comment: Oh, well that makes total sense. Thanks!